# React-css-modules: styleName is not recognized

Tags: css, reactjs, react-css-modules

I have a problem with react-css-modules. I am not able to find the classes that I have bound by the styleName. They do not appear as classes in the rendered html.

Here is the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import CSSModules from 'react-css-modules';
import styles from './ListItem.css'

@CSSModules(styles)
export class ListItem extends React.Component {
    render() {

        return (
            <li className="panel" styleName="list-item">
                <h3 className="uppercase m-t-0 m-b-0 relative" styleName="title">
                ...

                </h3>
            </li>);
        }
}
```

And the `webpack` configuration:

```
     module: {
        loaders: [
            ...
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loaders: [
                    require.resolve('style-loader'),
                    require.resolve('css-loader') + '?sourceMap&modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
                ]
            },
            ...
         ]
      }
```

So what is wrong here?

Comment: I don't know if this is a css-modules thing, but normally in React you would use `className` to add a class attribute to an element.

Comment: `styleName` comes from the css-modules.

Comment: @AnoushHakobyan Were you ever able to figure this out? I'm having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

If it helps, here is my loaders array in webpack config:

```
loaders: [
            'style?sourceMap',
            'css?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
          ]
```

Maybe the sourceMap being used in the styleLoader rather than the css loader has anything to do with it.

Also, you could try to avoid using the annotation `@CSSModules(styles)` and use the normal way, e.g. `export default CSSModules(ListItem, styles)` to see if there is an issue with the annotation.

Other than that, I can't see what's wrong.